# React native camera is not showing full screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-camera

I am new to camera in react-native. I am using Rect-native-camera to take pictures.

But I found it have some issues.

- Grid view is not available
- Unable to point only the nose in react-native-camera face detection
- Unable to find the distance of the face

And one of the main problem I ma facing is the camera view is not full screen. It is showing only 75%.

I tried adding thr height as 100% and the screen height. But nothing works.

This is my current code and the preview of camera UI.
[image: UI and code]
Can anyone help me rsolve these issues?

Answer (score 0):

As i can see react-native-camera is deprecated, in their docs they are suggesting to use [react-native-vision-camera](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera) . As i can in their docs, they have an option for full height .

Do check it out :

[image]